# Google Sheets: concat all items for each date

Tags: sql, google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

I have a list of dates and events in a Google Sheet

```
| date     | eventName |
 ------------------
| 21/05/16 |   evt1    |
| 21/05/16 |   evt2    |
| 30/05/16 |   evt3    |
| 01/06/16 |   evt1    |
| 01/06/16 |   evt4    |
```

I want to output a list of unique dates, with all events from that day concatenated together into 1 string like this:

```
| date     |     events  |
 ------------------------
| 21/05/16 |  evt1, evt2 |
| 30/05/16 |     evt3    |
| 01/06/16 |  evt1, evt4 |
```

I am completely stumped, I think I need a query of some kind, but can't figure out how to concatenate the event name strings together. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have the [sql] tag on this question?

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), I guess you were interested in using the [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) function to accomplish this. I don't know how to do that, since any [`GROUP BY`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#group-by) or [`PIVOT`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#pivot) operation requires an [aggregation function](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#aggregation_functions), and none of the supported aggregators can accomplish what you're asking.

Here's an alternative, using common formulas.

In your Google Spreadsheet, you can first use `UNIQUE()` to get the list of unique dates, and then a `FILTER()` in the next column to collect coincident events.

For example, here `D2` contains the formula `=UNIQUE($A$2:A)`, while `E2` contains `=join(", ",filter($B$2:$B,$A$2:$A=$D2))`, which is copied down to following cells.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In sql server :

I first create the following function that concatenates events for a single date

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[EventsDate] (@Date date) RETURNS varchar(50)
BEGIN 
DECLARE @Events VARCHAR(50)=''
SELECT @Events = @Events + case when len(@Events)>0 then ',' else '' end + eventName
FROM  (select eventName from [Events] nolock where [date]=@Date) as S
RETURN @Events
END
```

And then the request :

```
select [date], [dbo].[EventsDate]([date]) as eventsName from [Events] nolock group by [date]
```

Answer (score 0):

also try this formula:

```
={UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A>0)),TRANSPOSE(
   SPLIT(
      ", "&join(", ",
         ARRAYFORMULA(
            if(query(A:B,"select A where not A is null order by A",0)=
               query(A:B,"select A where not A is null order by A limit "&COUNT(query(A:B,"select A where not A is null",0))-1,1),"","|")
             & query(A:B,"select B where not A is null order by A",0)
             & " "
         )
      )
   ,", |",0)
)}
```

This is single formula solution.